# At which ordinal this "counting" ordinal language would fail?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, ordinals, ordinal-analysis

The language $FOL(=, \in , <, C)$ is mono-sorted first order predicate language with extra-logical primitives of equality (and its axioms), set membership, strict smaller than binary relation, and a two place function denoting "the count of an element in a set".

1. Well ordering: $<$ well orders the universe of elements.
2. Extensionality over sets (i.e., non-elements)
3. Flatness: $x \in y \to y \not \in z$
4. Counting: $x \in S \to C^S_x = lim^* \{ C^S_m | m \in S \land m < x\}$

Where $lim^* X$ is the upper strict limit on $X$, i.e. the ordinal immediately strictly larger than every element of $X$.

All elements in this theory are to be considered as "ordinals".

What is the expressive power of this language? I mean what is the limit to define ordinals in this language? for example one can define a regular ordinal $l$ as an element that is a limit ordinal, that is not the limit to a set $x$ of ordinals strictly smaller than it where $\lim^* \{C^x_m| m \in x\} < l$, that way we can define an inaccessible ordinal as a regular limit of regular ordinals. So this language has the expressive power to express inaccessibility.

> So at the level of which ordinal in the known large cardinal tower, this language would start to fail in providing a unique expression of?

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but (I think) that property (1) is not first order without some more axioms. In the language {=,<} with the usual equality axioms, "well-ordering" is not first order definable.

Comment: @Ned. The language of this theory is first order logic extended by the above primitives. Now property 1 is actually : < is a total order on elements + the schema: if $\phi$ is a formula (that hold of elements only), then all closures of: $\exists x \phi \to \exists x \phi \land \forall y (\phi \to x \leq y)$ are axioms.

Comment: What is $z$ in the flatness axiom?

Comment: Also since this is a first-order language well-ordering sounds difficult (if not impossible) to define as a single axiom since we can't quantify over sets of ordinals, does a transfinite induction schema work for the purpose of "the universe is well-ordered"?

Comment: @C7X, $\forall x,\forall y, \forall z$ is implicitly assumed before flatness axiom. The flatness axiom simply say that any nonempty set cannot be an element of a set. About the well ordering see my last commenht to Ned. The well ordering is a schema, not a single axiom.

Comment: In (4), does $S$ range over ordinals since the language is one-sorted?

Comment: Yes! because the language is mono-sorted, then $S$ does range over all objects, i.e. over ordinals as well as over sets of ordinals.